# iOS UIButton Fatal error when I use it for @IBOutlet

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, iboutlet

Hey I want to change my button's title, backgroundColor and width when I clicked
keep those things until I click the button again!

But there are some problems

It works for @IBAction func for the button
but it makes a fatal error when I change the title with

```
findRealTimeButton.setTitle("ALL", for: .normal)
```

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Also there is a problem when I changed the title of button in storyboard but it seems like changed but it doesn't in simulator

I thought it is a connection problem but it's not

Comment: Looks like you have added `findRealTimeButton.isSelected = true` ?  then `.normal` is diffrent scenario

Comment: @Jack Thanks Jack but it was a connection error from storyboard problem Thanks bruh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So "findRealTimeButton" is your @IBOutlet?

This error is almost definitely due to an unconnected @IBOutlet in your code. I would try deleting the line of code with your @IBOutlet, disconnecting the button from your storyboard, and running a Clean with CMD+Shift+K.

Then, I would ctrl-drag your button into your class using the assistant editor as normal, and I believe that it should work!

If that doesn't fix your problem, then I recommend using your debug window at the bottom of Xcode to check the value of "findRealTimeButton" under self.